# Creating a checkerboard, trouble with Pieces

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm attempting to create a checkerboard in Python. Currently, I have figured out the actual setup of the game itself, but I want to draw circles inside the squares to create 'game' pieces.

```
import turtle

turtle.bgcolor("Grey")

def drawRect(color):
    iterations = 0
    turtle.begin_fill() # Begin the fill process.
    turtle.down()
    turtle.color(color)

    while iterations < 4:
        turtle.forward(40)
        turtle.left(90)
        iterations += 1

    turtle.up() # Pen up
    turtle.end_fill()

def pushTurtleForward():
    turtle.forward(40)


def drawHorizontal(inverted):
    if(inverted):
        for horizontal in range(0, 8):
            if(horizontal > 0 and horizontal % 2 != 0):
                pushTurtleForward()
                drawRect("white")
            if(horizontal > 0 and horizontal % 2 == 0):
                pushTurtleForward()
                drawRect("black")
            if(horizontal == 0):
                drawRect("black")
    else:
        for horizontal in range(0, 8):
            if(horizontal > 0 and horizontal % 2 != 0):
                pushTurtleForward()
                drawRect("black")
            if(horizontal > 0 and horizontal % 2 == 0):
                pushTurtleForward()
                drawRect("white")
            if(horizontal == 0):
                drawRect("white")

for drawVertical in range(0, 8):
    turtle.setx(0)
    turtle.sety(40 * drawVertical)
    if(drawVertical % 2 == 0):
    drawHorizontal(inverted=True)
    else:
    drawHorizontal(inverted=False)

turtle.setx(0)
turtle.sety(0)
turtle.done()
```

I'm struggling with where I even put a loop to draw pieces for the game? Should it be a function on it's own that needs to be called? Can I place it somewhere inside the loops where the square is drawn?

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend that you not *draw* circles inside the squares, but rather create individual turtles to represent your checkers.  This will allow you to move checkers about your board without the need to erase a checker's old position and redraw the empty square.

I've reworked your code for style and added a demonstration section that randomly distributes a dozen red checkers about the black squares:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randrange

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
SQUARE_SIZE = 40
SQUARES_PER_SIDE = 8

def drawRect(color):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for iterations in range(4):
        turtle.forward(SQUARE_SIZE)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.penup()

def pushTurtleForward():
    turtle.forward(SQUARE_SIZE)

def drawHorizontal(inverted=False):
    if inverted:
        for horizontal in range(SQUARES_PER_SIDE):
            if horizontal > 0:
                if horizontal % 2 == 1:
                    pushTurtleForward()
                    drawRect("white")
                else:
                    pushTurtleForward()
                    drawRect("black")
            else:
                drawRect("black")
    else:
        for horizontal in range(SQUARES_PER_SIDE):
            if horizontal > 0:
                if horizontal % 2 == 1:
                    pushTurtleForward()
                    drawRect("black")
                else:
                    pushTurtleForward()
                    drawRect("white")
            else:
                drawRect("white")

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("Grey")

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')

for drawVertical in range(SQUARES_PER_SIDE):
    turtle.setposition(0, SQUARE_SIZE * drawVertical)

    if drawVertical % 2 == 0:
        drawHorizontal(inverted=True)
    else:
        drawHorizontal()

# Checker graphics demonstration.  Distribute 12 red checkers around
# black squares on board without any two landing on the same spot.

red_checkers = []

for _ in range(12):
    checker = Turtle('circle')
    checker.color('black', 'red')
    checker.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
    checker.penup()

    red_checkers.append(checker)

    position = checker.position()  # a position guaranteed to fail

    while any(map(lambda checker, p=position: checker.distance(p) < SQUARE_SIZE/2, red_checkers)):
        x, y = 0, 1  # a parity guaranteed to fail

        while x % 2 != y % 2:
            x, y = randrange(SQUARES_PER_SIDE), randrange(SQUARES_PER_SIDE)

        position = (x * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE/2, y * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE/2)

    checker.goto(position)


screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer cdlane. How many turtles can you reasonably create on a canvas? 100's? 1000's?

Comment: Thank you, I will look into using the different turtles if the loops do not line up properly! I think using turtles was my original plan but I wasn't sure about the location of the squares to get the circles right on top!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed a function on its own for the circles is a good idea.
In general for anything two-dimensional like a chessboard, the best thing is to use two loops inside each other (nested loops). The outer loop goes through all 8 rows, and for each row the inner loop goes through all 8 columns. Also in `drawRect`, what you do with the `while` loop is correct, but a `for` loop is more common for this purpose.

```
import turtle

fieldSize = 40
turtle.speed (0)

def drawRect(rowIndex, colIndex, color):
    turtle.sety (rowIndex * fieldSize)
    turtle.setx (colIndex * fieldSize)
    turtle.begin_fill() # Begin the fill process.
    turtle.down()
    turtle.color(color)
    for iterations in range(4):
        turtle.forward(fieldSize)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.end_fill()

def drawCircle(rowIndex, colIndex, color):
    turtle.sety (rowIndex * fieldSize)
    turtle.setx ((colIndex + 0.5) * fieldSize)
    turtle.begin_fill() # Begin the fill process.
    turtle.down()
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.circle(fieldSize / 2)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.end_fill()

for rowIndex in range (8):
    for colIndex in range (8):
        inverted = (rowIndex + colIndex) % 2 == 0
        drawRect (rowIndex, colIndex, 'black' if inverted else 'white')
        drawCircle (rowIndex, colIndex, 'white' if inverted else 'black')

turtle.done ()
```

Comment: Thank you! Loops are a tricky thing for me to understand, I will try out something similar to this!